# Is there a way to make a smart pointer that points to either a std::ifstream or std::cin?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, istream

I want to take input from an `istream` from either a `std::ifstream` or `std::cin` depending on some condition.

As far as I can get it working, I had to use a raw `std::istream*` pointer:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
    std::istream *in_stream;
    std::ifstream file;
    if (argc > 1) {
        std::string filename = argv[1];
        file.open(filename);
        if (not file.is_open()) {
            return -1;
        }
        in_stream = &file;
    } else {
        in_stream = &std::cin;
    }
    // do stuff with the input, regardless of the source...
}
```

Is there a way to rewrite the above using smart pointers?

Comment: A smart pointer does not make sense in this context.
`file`lives until this function exits. You use smart pointers only when you use dynamic memory. But thats not the case here.

Comment: Why do you want a smart pointer? Are you trying to make sure that `std::cin` is destroyed at some point?

Comment: I would write a function `do_stuff(std::istream& input)` and then pass one of the streams to it. No need for pointers.

Comment: All these `istream`-related classes actually already are smart pointers!  The object they manage is an instance of some class derived from `streambuf`.

Answer (score 2):

A smart pointer is kind of an awkward fit for this situation, because it requires a dynamic allocation (which is probably not necessary in this case)

---

##### 1. Do your processing in another function

As @BoP pointed out in the comments a nice way to handle this could be to use another function that gets passed the appropriate input stream:

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/PErPhP6E5)

```cpp
int do_thing(std::istream& in_stream) {
    // do stuff with the input, regardless of the source...
    int foobar;
    in_stream >> foobar;

    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
    std::ofstream{"/tmp/foobar"} << 1234;

    if(argc > 1) {
        std::ifstream file{argv[1]};
        if(!file) return -1;

        return do_thing(file);
    } else {
        return do_thing(std::cin);
    }
}
```

---

##### 2. Switch the stream buffer

If you won't be using `std::cin` at all if a filename is passed you could change the streambuffer of `std::cin` to the one of the file with [`rdbuf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf) - that way you can use `std::cin` in both cases.

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/74z16KEhW)

```cpp
std::ifstream file;
std::streambuf* oldbuf = std::cin.rdbuf();
    
if (argc > 1) {
    file.open(argv[1]);
    if (!file) return -1;

    // switch buffer of std::cin
    std::cin.rdbuf(file.rdbuf());
}

// do stuff with the input, regardless of the source...
int foobar;
std::cin >> foobar; // this will reader either from std::cin or the file, depending on the current streambuffer assigned to std::cin


// restore old stream buffer
std::cin.rdbuf(oldbuf);
```

---

##### 3. Using `std::unique_ptr` / `std::shared_ptr` with a custom deleter

The easiest solution if you still want to use smart pointers would be to use `std::unique_ptr` / `std::shared_ptr` with a custom deleter that handles the `std::cin` case:

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/WTdG9xoPj)

```cpp
// deletes the stream only if it is not std::cin
struct istream_ptr_deleter {
    void operator()(std::istream* stream) {
        if(&std::cin == stream) return;
        delete stream;
    }
};

using istream_ptr = std::unique_ptr<std::istream, istream_ptr_deleter>;


// Example Usage:
istream_ptr in_stream;
if (argc > 1) {
    in_stream.reset(new std::ifstream(argv[1]));
    if (!*in_stream) return -1;
} else {
    in_stream.reset(&std::cin);
}

int foobar;
*in_stream >> foobar;
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be a question about **ownership**: How does one wrap and pass around two different `std::istream` instances, one of which is owned and needs disposal (which calls `close()` upon destruction) and ownership transfers, whereas the other one is *not* owned by user code (e.g. `std::cin`) and cannot be `delete`d. The solution is polymorphism: Create an interface like

```cpp
struct StreamWrapper {
  virtual std::istream &stream() = 0;
  virtual ~StreamWrapper() = default;
};
```

and two implementations, e.g. `OwnedStreamWrapper` and `UnownedStreamWrapper`. The former can contain a `std::istream` directly (which is moveable, but not copyable) and the latter can contain (e.g.) a `std::istream&`, i.e. have no ownership over the referenced stream instance.

```cpp
struct OwnedStreamWrapper : public StreamWrapper {
  template <typename... A>
  OwnedStreamWrapper(A &&...a) : stream_{std::forward<A>(a)...} {}
  std::istream &stream() override { return stream_; }

 private:
  std::ifstream stream_;
};

struct UnownedStreamWrapper : public StreamWrapper {
  UnownedStreamWrapper(std::istream &stream) : stream_{stream} {}
  std::istream &stream() override { return stream_; }

 private:
  std::istream &stream_;
};
```

Apart from the stream ownership, wrapper ownership matters as well and can be used either to handle the wrappers’ (and streams’) lifespan automatically on the stack, or to allow a wrapper’s lifespan to exceed that of the current stack frame. In the example below, the first `ReadWrapper()` takes ownership of the wrapper and `delete`s it automatically whereas the second `ReadWrapper()` does not take ownership. In both cases polymorphism (i.e. the implementation of `StreamWrapper`) determines how the underlying stream is handled, i.e. whether it outlives its wrapper (like `std::cin` should) or dies together with it (like a manually instantiated stream should).

```cpp
void ReadWrite(std::istream &in, std::ostream &out) {
  std::array<char, 1024> buffer;
  while (in) {
    in.read(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
    out.write(buffer.data(), in.gcount());
  }
}

void ReadWrapper(std::unique_ptr<StreamWrapper> stream) {
  ReadWrite(stream->stream(), std::cout);
}

void ReadWrapper(StreamWrapper &stream) {
  ReadWrite(stream.stream(), std::cout);
}
```

Below are all four combinations of { owned | unowned } { streams | stream wrappers } in a runnable example:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

namespace {

/********** The three snippets above go here! **********/

}  // namespace

int main() {
  OwnedStreamWrapper stream1{"/proc/cpuinfo"};
  std::unique_ptr<StreamWrapper> stream2{
      std::make_unique<OwnedStreamWrapper>("/proc/cpuinfo")};
  std::ifstream stream3_file{"/proc/cpuinfo"};  // Let’s pretend it is unowned.
  UnownedStreamWrapper stream3{stream3_file};
  std::ifstream stream4_file{"/proc/cpuinfo"};  // Let’s pretend it is unowned.
  std::unique_ptr<StreamWrapper> stream4{
      std::make_unique<UnownedStreamWrapper>(stream4_file)};

  ReadWrapper(stream1);             // owned stream, wrapper kept
  ReadWrapper(std::move(stream2));  // owned stream, wrapper transferred
  ReadWrapper(stream3);             // unowned stream, wrapper kept
  ReadWrapper(std::move(stream4));  // unowned stream, wrapper transferred
}
```